Why is my snippet not executing after the for loop?
public void processSobjects(List<sObject> sobjs){
    Map<Id, sObject> sobjsToUpdate = new Map<Id, sObject>();
    for(sObject sob : sobjs){
        //SOME LOGIC HERE
        system.debug('PUTTING INSIDE MAP');
        sobjsToUpdate.put(sob.Id, sob);
        System.debug('PUTTING INSIDE MAP3' + sobjsToUpdate.get(sob.Id));
    }
    System.debug('%%% ');
    List<SObject> sobjList = sobjsToUpdate.values();
    System.debug('%%% ' + sobjList.size());
    for(SObject s1 : sobjList){
        system.debug('%%%');
        system.debug('%%%s1**' + s1.get('Firstname') + ' ' + s1.get('LastName'));
        system.debug('%%%s2**' + s1.get('Integration_Status__c'));
    }
    sobjList.sort();
    update sobjList;
}

The weird thing is I can see the Debug For PUTTING INSIDE MAP and PUTTING INSIDE MAP3. After the loop statement I am just logging %%% but I cannot see it. What might be the potential cause?
EDIT: Fixed the code to simplify

I have tried your code in my org and I can see the debug log: https://tinyurl.com/2dlqgy8f
Highlighted Code Executed: https://tinyurl.com/2cw5q2bc

You can also try to wrap the method in a try-catch block so if any error then you can see catch and debug. like this: public void processSobjects(List<sObject> sobjs) {         try {                 //your code         } catch (Exception ex) {                 System.debug('Exception: ' + ex.getMessage() + ' In LineNumber: '+ ex.getLineNumber());         } }

It didn't went in any exception.

I'm assuming you are referring to the first for loop in your code for your question. From what you have shared, there isn't any reason it won't execute as expected. You may need to share a more complete copy of your code as we can't help you with what you've currently supplied.

Running your code in any org through the developer console results in the code execution being completed successfully under some conditions:

The Integration_Status__c field is created on the Salesforce object being used on the list, or line 15 is commented out.
The FirstName field exists already on the Salesforce object being used on the list, or line 14 is commented out.
Line 18, with the update statement, is commented out.

This snippet works for me under those conditions:
List<Contact> accounts = new List<Contact>{
    new Contact(FirstName='Acme')
};
    
processSobjects(accounts);

So perhaps the issue with your code is that the function is being called from somewhere else and within a try/catch block? That would result the code being executed successfully until it hits an error on the second loop, if that's the case. Otherwise, there's objectively no reason for your code to fail before hitting the update statement at the end.
